# Cocoa Touch Subclass UIScrollView and Custom Delegate Still Receive Parent Delegate Messages

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have subclassed UIScrollView and added my own custom delegate (currently called `delegate`). I want to add functionality such as notifying a user when an image is tapped and perform loading like the table view.

However, If I define my own custom delegate, I can not set the parent delegate for responding to events such as `scrollViewDidScroll` (I want the subclass to receive these events). Should I rename the delegate in my subclass? Should I be using `super.delegate` in some form? Does a standard exist for doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your custom delegate just extend the methods of UIScrollViewDelegate?  If it does, just override the methods `-scrollViewDidScroll` etc and forward the messages onto your own delegate.

Maybe I've misunderstood your question, so I apologize if I have.

Comment: It implements an entirely new protocol. The issue is that the custom UIScrollView is extending the delegate, while still implementing its own delegate.